# ASP.NET MVC Display Template Performance Issue

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, debugging

Just saw that one of my pages was EXTREMELY slow, so I started debugging it and found several threads on the internet [Stopping the panic: how to improve HtmlHelper.RenderPartial performances. Don’t run in debug mode](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/04/22/how-to-improve-htmlhelper.renderpartial-performances-donrsquot-run-in-debug-mode.aspx) that is was due do debug="true" in the  settings in the web.config file.

That was partly true ... on IIS Express it don't work, but when I publish the site to a IIS 7.5 it fast.

IIS Express 2.4sec.
IIS 7.5 132ms

Same site ... same config.

#### From the link

```
protected VirtualPathProviderViewEngine()
{
  if (HttpContext.Current == null || HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled)
    this.ViewLocationCache = DefaultViewLocationCache.Null;
  else
    this.ViewLocationCache = (IViewLocationCache) new DefaultViewLocationCache();
}
```

So ofcause I tried to see what the values was when running my web app in IIS Express.

```
HttpContext: False
IsDebuggingEnabled: False
```

So ... I must be doing something wrong here. The question is what? Does IIS Express have that bad performance? There is about 100 Html.DisplayFor on the page ... but 132ms vs 2.4sec is just way too much off a difference.

Please let me know how I can debug this ...

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue. Running 1000 DisplayFor in a Razor view. In Debug mode it takes 700ms, in Release 100ms, almost the same as when I deploy it in IIS 7.5. On the server it's a bit faster because the hardware is much better than my laptop but not a noticeable difference.

Comment: I should maybe also have mentioned that I have manually upgrade the project to MVC 4. I will try with a fresh MVC project and move all my code. But I think its odd if that solves my problem.